# Django superuser not allowed to edit this model

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-permissions

Since recently I need to work home, but Django is working against me. I'm having a very peculier issue. I clone the repo, create a MySQL schema, migrate, dump all the data from the server into my local db so I have something to work with, start the server and I log in as the superuser.

Now this is basically a job vacancy app for our company. These are my models:

- Status
- Department
- Location
- Contactperson
- Vacancy
- Applicant

I can edit entries for anything not related to a department, which are statuses, locations or contacts. But when it comes to the rest, I get a error messsage saying my user is not allowed to edit these. An applicant is related to a vacancy which is related to a department, so I get the error message at all of these.

```
class DepartmentAdminForm(ModelForm):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}
    readonly_fields = ['banner_image', 'button_background_image_location']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        self.obj = kwargs.pop('obj', None)
        super(DepartmentAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if self.instance.pk is None:  # add
            return cleaned_data

        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        user = self.request.user
        is_authorized = department_role_check(self.obj, user)

        if is_authorized:
            return cleaned_data
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError('You are not allowed to edit this department.')

    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = [
            'name',
            'summary',
            'slug',
            'button_short_text',
            'position',
        ]

        verbose_name = 'Departments'
```

This is a pretty standard AdminForm. And it works just fine on production. I have not pushed any changes to the repo to this point which would make the code different on production.
Another very weird part with this is, when I revoke superuser status from the user and give it all the permissions, all the department entries dissapear and leave only 2 out of the 11 vacancies visible... which should not happen, right?

I'm at a complete loss here...
I hope someone can shine some light on this.

EDIT: here is where the role check happens, in guards.py in the same map as where settings is located

```
def department_role_check(department, user):
    permission = 'departments.department_' + str(department.id)

    return permission in user.get_group_permissions()

def department_vacancy_role_check(department, user):
    permission = 'vacancies.vacancy_department_' + str(department.id)

    return permission in user.get_group_permissions()

def vacancy_role_check(vacancy, user):
    permission = 'vacancies.vacancy_department_' + str(vacancy.department.id)

    return permission in user.get_group_permissions()

def vacancy_applicant_role_check(applicant, user):
    try:
        permission = 'vacancies.vacancy_department_' + str(applicant.vacancy.department.id)
        return permission in user.get_group_permissions()

    except Exception:
        return False
```

Also, the user **is** allowed to create new departments and vacancies (granted they are related to new departments) and edit those which doesn't make sense to me

Comment: You'll need to post the implementation for `department_role_check`.

Comment: Ah right, stupid of me. I added it to the post!